# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm testing my app with rspec,I read that I have to create an user in test enviroment but don't know how.... here is the code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe CarsController do
    describe "GET 'new'" do
            it "should be successful" do
            visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")#also try (current_user) but nothing
            response.should be_success
            end
        end
    end
```

When I run it I got this message

```
Failure/Error: visit new_user_car_path(:user_id=>"28")
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find User with id=28
 # ./app/controllers/cars_controller.rb:3:in `new'
 # ./spec/controllers/tanking_logs_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If you need more code, tell me

EDIT. I tried this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CarsController do
describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
        #user = User.create(...)
        @user = {:email => "user@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" }
        visit new_user_car_path(@user) 
        response.should be_success
    end
end
end
```

and I got this error now:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars", :email=>"user@example.com", :password=>"foobar", :password_confirmation=>"foobar"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a user with ID 28 in your testing database. You need to seed your testing database and use the ID of a user you know to exist.

Alternatively, create a new User on demand:

```
describe "GET 'new'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    user = User.create(...)
    visit new_user_car_path(user)#also try (current_user) but nothing
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: You have three databases: development, production, test. The record you are searching for exists in your development database, but not your test database. So you must create the object in your test database. Alternatively, you can change your test database to be your development database but this is not recommended because you want your test database to be cordoned off.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you up and running, but is by no means a good way to run your tests.

So, if you have a user with id = 28 in your development db, you can tell Rspec to to run tests against this db instead of the default test db.

In your spec_helper.rb
Replace this

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

With

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'development'
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your spec is changed you are getting a routing error.

What's happening is that rails is trying to create a new car in cars#new (that means `cars_controller` and the `new` action but you don't have that route.

run `rake routes` to see what routes you have and post that.